# How do I make this code shorter by using arrays

Tags: java

How do I make this code shorter by using `Arrays`? This is part of a larger code where I simulated the lottery. this specific portion is where the user numbers are generated and I cant seem to figure out how to make this into an `Array`.

```
public static void compypick()
{
    boolean done;
    Random  randomgen = new Random();
    winn0 = randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1;

    done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        winn1 = randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1;
        if (winn1 != winn0)
            done = true;
    }
    done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        winn2 = randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1;
        if ((winn2 != winn1) && (winn2 != winn0))
            done = true;
    }
    done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        winn3 = randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1;
        if ((winn3 != winn2) && (winn3 != winn1) && (winn3 != winn0))
            done = true;
    }
    done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        winn4 = randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1;
        if ((winn4 != winn3) && (winn4 != winn2) && (winn4 != winn1) && (winn4 != winn0))
            done = true;
    }
    done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        winn5 = randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1;
        if ((winn5 != winn4) && (winn5 != winn3) && (winn5 != winn2) && (winn5 != winn1) && (winn5 != winn0))
            done = true;
    }
    System.out.printf ("Winning numbers: %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", winn0, winn1, winn2, winn3, winn4, winn5);
}
```

Comment: So, you want to pick the six numbers out of set [1-53]?

Answer (score 1):

If they need to be unique you can use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
while(set.size() < 6) {
    set.add(randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1);
}
```

Or java 8+ you can use the [`ints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) method to get a `Stream` and collect it to a `Set`:

```
Random random = new Random();
Set<Integer> set = random.ints(0, 54)                          
                         .distinct().limit(6)
                         .boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or:

```
Set<Integer> set = random.ints(6, 1, 53).distinct().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

***Sample output:***

```
48 3 41 25 11 31
```

Comment: be very careful with `random.ints(0, 54).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());` as `random.ints(0, 54)` returns an _infinite stream_ and currently there is no short-circuiting operation to consume the stream. consider using `limit` or simply use the 3 arg version of `random.ints` where the first argument is the size of the stream.

Comment: @Aomine Yes I just realized I forgot that. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Also, both your solutions are correct in the sense that the values in the accumulating set will have "unique" values but they're incorrect in "assuming" that the accumulating set will always have 6 "unique" values. you'll need to call `distinct` before `limit` for the Java-8 solution. now that we've used `distinct` you might even consider collecting to a List instead of a Set.

Comment: The same comment under the @Aomine answer could be applied here.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using just arrays would be this:

```
public static boolean contains(int[] array, int x) {
    for (int i : array) {
        if (i == x) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random randomgen = new Random();
    int[] winningNumbers = new int[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        int winn = randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1;
        while(contains(winningNumbers, winn)){
            winn = randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1;
        }
        winningNumbers[i] = winn;
    }

    System.out.printf("Winning numbers: ");
    for (int i: winningNumbers) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in reducing your current code to some good extent:

```
String result = random.ints(6, 1, 54) // IntStream
                .distinct() // IntStream of distinct values
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString) // Stream<String>
                .collect(joining(" ", "Winning numbers: ", "")); // String
System.out.println(result);
```

If you want to persist the unique winning numbers after printing then you could do:

```
int[] res = random.ints(6, 1, 53) // IntStream
                  .distinct() // IntStream of distinct values
                  .toArray();

System.out.printf ("Winning numbers: %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", 
                res[0], res[1], res[2], res[3], res[4], res[5]);
// still have access to "res" later on for further processing...
```

Comment: This is a good answer for these inputs, but consider picking 9999 out of 10000 elements, or even more. I mean `distinct()` would pay price in the time performance.

Comment: @zlakad since when can you have around "9999" winning numbers? do you want the company to go bankrupt? ^_^. the generated numbers will always be a small amount so no need to worry about performance.

Comment: I'm just thinking theoretically - some similar problem. Of course, my example is not good enough, since we can pick just **one** _missing_ element, and print the rest, but 50_000 from set of 100_000?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fine for this job, but I think sets are a better choice, as you want *unique* numbers. You should also use a for loop. You are basically repeating some operation five times.

```
Set<Integer> winningNumbers = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    while (true)
    {
        int number = randomgen.nextInt(53) + 1;
        if (winningNumbers.add(number)) { // "add" returns false if the element already exists in the set
            break;
        }
    }
}
// printing the numbers:
System.out.println("Winning numbers: " + winningNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the domain set has only 53 elements, you can chose this approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //populate 'box'
        //(you can do it only once in the static block)
        List<Integer> balls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 53 ; i++) {
            balls.add(i);
        }

        //shuffle the balls in the box
        Collections.shuffle(balls);

        //pick the first six elements
        List<Integer> userBalls = balls.subList(0, 6);

        //optionally you can sort the user balls
        userBalls.sort(Integer::compareTo);

        //print
        System.out.println(userBalls);
    }
}
```